# Capitalized common datatypes in pre-installed libraries (Int, Char, etc)

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors

I'm developing some multimedia software on embedded linux, and using an open source library I've happened upon.  This library is from the vendor, and comes pre-installed on the hardware.  I can confirm that the GNU install process works to build/link/install this library via `autogen/make`, however, the header files used for making my own program all specify common datatypes with capital letters.  In C.  So I am seeing datatypes called `Int` and `Char`. The code blocks with the strange capitalized datatypes are within an `extern C` block, and C++ doesn't accept `Int` as a datatype anyway!

So I am having issues compiling when I'm using these libraries.  The autogen-generated `makefile` seems to take its flags from the environment, and I do not want to recompile the libraries every time I need to compile my program.

Is there any way I can compile my own code (which is just written in C) without having to modify these libraries, which were made specifically for this hardware?

CLARITY EDIT: My task is to compile a small C program, which relies upon header files with erroneous datatypes that came preinstalled.  I do not want to edit or recompile these hardware-specific header files.

Comment: `extern "C"` is a C++ construct. It is **not** C. And it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish or what the actual problem is.

Comment: Standard C doesn't accept such type names either, unless they have been `typedef`ed or defined as macros.  C++ should be able to handle those alternatives too.

Comment: I agree that the nature of the problem and what you are trying to accomplish are unclear.  Certainly it seems unlikely that you would need to modify vendor-provided libraries, and I see no reason whatever to think that you would need to compile them more than once.  I'm uncertain why you think either of these is even reasonable.

Comment: I don't want to modify or recompile these libraries, I guess I didn't make that clear enough.  But I also haven't found any `typedef` changes to make these datatypes.

I am aware that `extern "C"` is a C++ construct.  I am also aware of what it does.

I will modify the original question to make it more clear.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't some kind of common prefix header for this library which defines these types appropriately for the platform, e.g. `typedef int32_t Int;` or something like that ?

Comment: There is something like that in a file that I have `#include`'d in my own program, however some of the errors persist when I try to compile.  I may actually have this sorted.  The `typedef` was part of a different library edit: a word

Comment: I solved the problem.  There was an incorrect  preprocessor macro `define` in one of the headers, which enabled the typedef declarations that were causing issues.  I changed the typo and recompiled, all is well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not be doing the import/include part so the compiler understands the new types.  You shouldn't have to modify the library but you might have to change how you include it.  The `extern C` isn't enough as it is just a hint to the linker.  C++ can accept `Int` or `Char` as a datatype if it is properly told about the declaration.  Well, they aren't really going to be true types but likely will be typedef structs, or even more likely they are handled through preprocessor macros.  I would be willing to bet that they've used `#define`'s so the `Int` is transformed into the actual typedef statements.

Do you have any example code that came with the library? Can you post any of the headers from the library?

[Edit]
On line 100 of `Engine.h` is the following:
`typedef Int Engine_Error;` which says to me you must not be including the appropriate headers.  You also didn't include the error you get from compiling, does it say unknown identifier for `Int` or does it not find `Engine_Error`. If the former, then you aren't including `Engine.h`, if the latter, you aren't including whichever header that contains the definition of `Engine_Error`.

Comment: What you say seems mostly right, but I don't see how it answers the question actually posed: "Is there any way I can compile my own code (which is just written in C) without having to modify these libraries, which were made specifically for this hardware?"  That you're asking for more information strongly suggests that this would be better as a comment.

Comment: I thought about using a comment but what I wanted to say seemed a bit long for a comment. It's an answer because you shouldn't typically have to modify a library in order to use it. It wouldn't surprise me if it gets closed as too broad either.

Comment: [this library is the one I am using](http://git.omapzoom.org/repo/libdce.git/?p=repo/libdce.git;a=tree;h=ecb3577c9b3df4a09cf9a764320daa65b6057817;hb=398dd27e7f3181fff9e3d910b418c69f1493f52f).  The offending files are `Engine.h`, and most of the header files in the `packages` repository

Comment: Yep, that was more or less what was happening.  There was a preprocessor macro that was not defined in `xdc/std.h`, and was messing up the `typedef`'s.  Including that fixed the issue